# Overlap UITableView by it's own UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I have implemented a custom view inside a `UITableView` `cell` which acts as a searchable **dropdown**. It works well as long as the list of suggestions (using `UITableView`) is shorter than the main `UITableView`.

[image]

However, the problem happens when the list of suggestions is longer than the main `UITableView`.

[image]

The list of suggestions should overlap the main `UITableView`. How can I make it overlap the main `UITableView`?

Comment: add dropdown outside of tableview not inside

Comment: tableView.clipsToBounds = false

Comment: Would suggest you to add the list on top of table view, but as a subview to tableview's superview. Second, no matter where you add, I think the list of countries would always be long enough to require scrolling, hence, it would be better to give it a max height Like, if there are more than 5 rows in search, it would be max height, or it would be height of the contentSize. Something like that.

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik clipsToBounds doesn't work unfortunately